# Intro to Linux cli; output redirection

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, io-redirection, cp

Why does cp a b result in error when cp a b > a results in no error when neither a nor b file exists.

From my understanding cp a b gives error because neither file exists, makes sense and cp a b >a seems to create both files and copy blank from b to a but the reason a is empty is because output of the operation does not actually produce any messages.

Please let me know what the correct explanation is. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `cp a b > a`, the first thing the shell does is create the file `a`.  It then creates a child and redirects its output to that file before the child execs `cp`.  So `a` exists before `cp` starts, and it happily copies the file.